# How to declare generic, mapped types for this dependency-injection container in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typescript-typings

I've come up with this simple, asynchronous dependency-injection container in TypeScript:

```js
function Container<P extends { [name: string]: { (c: any): Promise<any> } }>(provider: P) {
    const cache: { [name in keyof P]?: Promise<any> } = {};

    const container = function(name: keyof P) {
        if (!cache[name]) {
            cache[name] = provider[name](container);
        }

        return cache[name];
    }

    return container;
}
```

Here's a simple use-case example:

```js
class UserCache { }

class UserService {
    constructor(private cache: UserCache) { }
}

let container = Container({
    "cache": async c => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async c => new UserService(await c("cache"))
});

container("user-service").then(service => {
    console.log(service);
});
```

So to briefly explain what's expected here: the `Container` function is basically a "type-cast" that takes a map of service-definitions (a `provider`) and returns a factory-function aka the `container`. The service-definitions receive the `container` instance, so that they can look up their dependencies, and return a `Promise` that resolves to the service instance.

I need help with the type-declarations.

I've gotten as far as type-checking the `name` argument - the resulting `container` function accepts only keys that exist in the `provider`, so far, so good.

What's missing is the generic return-type of calls to the `container`, so that, in turn, nested service-look-ups such as `await c("cache")` can be resolved and type-checked correctly.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is to make the compiler to infer correct type for this `container`:

```
let container = Container({
    "cache": async c => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async c => new UserService(await c("cache"))
});
```

But it depends on the type of the argument which is passed to `Container`, which is an object literal, so compiler looks at the type of property initializers:

```
async c => new UserCache()
```

and sees that `c` does not have type annotation, so it's type must be inferred, and the constraint is that it's the same type as `container` - oops, TypeScript does not equipped well to do type inference with circular constraints.

`c` gets inferred as `any`, there's no way around it:

```
// let's start with imaginary type P which maps names to provided types

// and declare desired container type
type ContainerFunc<P> = <N extends keyof P>(n: N) => Promise<P[N]>;

// and its argument type
type ProviderType<P> = { [N in keyof P]: (c: ContainerFunc<P>) => Promise<P[N]> };


function Container<P>(provider: ProviderType<P>): ContainerFunc<P> {
    const cache: { [N in keyof P]?: Promise<P[N]> } = {};

    const container = function<N extends keyof P>(name: N): Promise<P[N]> {
        if (!cache[name]) {
            cache[name] = provider[name](container);
        }

        return cache[name];
    }

    return container;
}

class UserCache { cache: {} }

class UserService {
    constructor(private cache: UserCache) { }
}

let container = Container({
    "cache": async c => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async c => new UserService(await c("cache"))
});
```

To remove circularity, you have to remove `c` parameter - it's always the `container` itself, let's use it as such:

```
type ContainerFunc<P> = <N extends keyof P>(n: N) => Promise<P[N]>;

type ProviderType<P> = { [N in keyof P]: () => Promise<P[N]> };

function Container<P>(provider: ProviderType<P>): ContainerFunc<P> {
    const cache: { [N in keyof P]?: Promise<P[N]> } = {};

    const container = function<N extends keyof P>(name: N): Promise<P[N]> {
        if (!cache[name]) {
            cache[name] = provider[name]();
        }

        return cache[name];
    }

    return container;
}

class UserCache { cache: {} }

class UserService {
    constructor(private cache: UserCache) { }
}

let container = Container({
    "cache": async () => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async () => new UserService(await container("cache"))
});
```

But now `container` type is inferred as `any`, because initializer for `"user-service"` refers to `container` in the function body, which prevents inferring that function return type.

You have to add return type annotation:

```
let container = Container({
    "cache": async () => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async (): Promise<UserService> => new UserService(await container("cache"))
});
```

Now it's working:

```
let container = Container({
    "cache": async () => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async (): Promise<UserService> => new UserService(await container("user-service"))
});

// error: Argument of type 'UserService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserCache'.
```

I believe it's the best that you can get.

**Update** as you suggested in comment, the other way to avoid circularity is to spell out all provider names and provided types in advance, before the implementation:

```
type ContainerFunc<P> = <N extends keyof P>(n: N) => Promise<P[N]>;

type ProviderType<P> = { [N in keyof P]: (c: ContainerFunc<P>) => Promise<P[N]> };


function Container<P>(provider: ProviderType<P>): ContainerFunc<P> {
    const cache: { [N in keyof P]?: Promise<P[N]> } = {};

    const container = function<N extends keyof P>(name: N): Promise<P[N]> {
        if (!cache[name]) {
            cache[name] = provider[name](container);
        }

        return cache[name];
    }

    return container;
}

class UserCache { cache: {} }

class UserService {
    constructor(private cache: UserCache) { }
}

interface ProviderTypes {
    cache: UserCache;
    "user-service": UserService;
}

let container = Container<ProviderTypes>({
    "cache": async c => new UserCache(),
    "user-service": async c => new UserService(await c("cache"))
});
```

Comment: Yeah this was the solution I was thinking about as well, the circular nature of the object literal type makes the compiler refuse to infer the type unfortunately. Would the op be interested in an alternative approach that does not use a single object literal for initialization? I believe we could get a better solution with such an apoach?

Comment: @artem does it matter what type the c argument is? whether it's the container or an identical, anonymous type - shouldn't matter. can we duplicate the declaration?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'd be fine with refactoring to a class with a get-method, if that makes it possible?

Comment: [refactored to a class](https://gist.github.com/mindplay-dk/deb04e6f8a54b898f4b6bf48ee9aac89) if either of you can figure out how to type-hint the container argument? :-)

Comment: @mindplay.dk I was not necessarily thinking about the container being a class, the way we build the container is the problem, I added an alternative solution, hope it helps

Comment: what if keep the container immutable and add a chainable factory-method that returns a new container? `let container = Container().with(X).with(Y)` etc. - or does that just create a different version of the same problem? hmm.

Comment: @mindplay yes if you don't mind writing a somewhat duplicate declaration with the same provider names explicitly giving provided types - it can also work. I updated my answer.

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer - it's probably the closest we can get, although it's a bit disappointing that the type-system doesn't work better for this case. Seems like it should be possible to make this type-safe without repeating a bunch of information, but, oh well.

Comment: @artem any chance this newer feature [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) can be used get the inference I was hoping for?

Answer (score 3):

As @artem mentioned, the compiler refuses to infer the type of an object literal if the inferred type references itself in any way (it's an outright limitation, the compiler will even mention this), so for the current structure you have @artem's answer is the best you are going to get.

A refactoring you could consider is one where you don't add the providers in one go, but rather using an `add` method on a container builder class. The return type of the add will return a new container builder that can resolve the types added up until that point so a newly added service can only make use of services already registered (making lemonade out of lemons, this might not be totally bad as it avoids circular references)

An implementation would look something like this:

```
function Container() {
    type ContainerFunc<P> = <N extends keyof P>(n: N) => P[N];
    class ContainerBuilder<T extends { [P in keyof T]: Promise<any> }> {
        public constructor(private provider: { [P in keyof T]: (c: any) => T[P] } = {} as any) {

        }
        public add<K extends string, V>(name: K, p: (c: ContainerFunc<T>)=> Promise<V>): ContainerBuilder<T & { [P in K]: Promise<V> }> {
            this.provider[name] = p;
            return this as any;
        }

        finish() : ContainerFunc<{ [P in keyof T]: T[P]}> {
            const provider = this.provider;
            const cache: { [name in keyof T]?: Promise<any> } = {};
            const container = function<K extends keyof T>(name: K) : T[K]  {
                if (!cache[name]) {
                    cache[name] = provider[name](container);
                }

                return cache[name] as any;
            }
            return container as any;

        }
    }

    return new ContainerBuilder()
}

class UserCache { }
class OfficeCache {}
class UserService {
    constructor(private cache: UserCache, private officeCache?: OfficeCache) { }
}


var c = Container()
    .add("user", async ()=> new UserCache())
    // all typed corectly, no any, the comented code below would be an error as office has not been registered yet
    .add("user-service", async c=> new UserService(await c("user") /* , await c("office") */)) 
    .add("office", async c=> new OfficeCache())
.finish();

let userService = c("user-service");
```

Comment: "the compiler refuses to infer the type of an object literal if the inferred type references itself" - but does it have to? the container argument doesn't have to be the same type, it could be a different (maybe anonymous) type with an identical signature. we can't avoid the circular inference that way?

Comment: @mindplay.dk There is no way to type `c` except relative to the current object literal, and this is the relation that will cause the compiler to complain. Because to type `c` it needs to know the type of the object literal, and to fully type the object literal it needs to know the type of `c`..

Comment: @mindplay.dk I see artem updated his answer, if you are willing to write out the providers in an interface before hand, that will work, I hadn't considered this approach as spelling out the providers twice seems like too much overhead...